# how to config ignore null check in release mode with flutter build

Tags: flutter

Now I am compile project in release mode tell me some package did not support null check.

```
This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that
    need to be translated.
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A
    library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
    // @dart = 2.8
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A
    library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
    // @dart = 2.8
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
    don't support null safety:

     - package:shared_preferences
     - package:timeago
     - package:hive
     - package:hive_flutter
     - package:state_notifier
     - package:fish_redux
     - package:flutter_hooks
     - package:shared_preferences_linux
     - package:shared_preferences_platform_interface
     - package:shared_preferences_windows
     - package:crypto
     - package:path_provider
     - package:path_provider_linux
     - package:path_provider_windows
     - package:path_provider_platform_interface
     - package:xdg_directories
     - package:convert
     - package:plugin_platform_interface
     - package:pull_to_refresh
     - package:flutter_icons
     - package:animations
     - package:flutter_slidable
     - package:http
     - package:fluttertoast
     - package:share
     - package:flutter_secure_storage
     - package:logger
     - package:dio
     - package:intl_phone_number_input
     - package:url_launcher
     - package:flutter_html
     - package:mime
     - package:http_parser
     - package:url_launcher_platform_interface
     - package:webview_flutter
     - package:uni_links
     - package:equatable
     - package:libphonenumber
     - package:csslib
     - package:html
     - package:flutter_layout_grid
     - package:chewie
     - package:chewie_audio
     - package:video_player
     - package:shimmer
     - package:video_player_platform_interface
     - package:quiver
     - package:wakelock
     - package:wakelock_platform_interface

    For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

how to ignore null check in release mode in flutter when build app in fastlane? I already know to add parameter when build in local like this:

```
~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

how to add `--no-sound-null-safety` into xcode build release mode as a default build parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on the GitHub Actions workflow file add the step(do not need add in Fastlane):

```
- run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --no-sound-null-safety
```

would fix this(Since upgrade to flutter 2.0.1). This is the full workflow file:

```
name: Cruise-CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    #
    # more macOS version:
    # https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md
    #
    runs-on: macos-10.15
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '12.x'
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '2.0.1'
      #
      # more xcode version path:
      # https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md
      #
      - name: Select Xcode version
        run: sudo xcode-select -s '/Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer'
      - name: Bundle install
        run: |
          cd ./ios
          brew install gpg
          curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
          curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
          echo 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3:6: | gpg --import-ownertrust
          echo 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB:6: | gpg --import-ownertrust
          curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
          source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
          source ~/.bash_profile
          rvm --version
          rvm install 2.7.2
          rvm use --default 2.7.2
          gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0
          gem install fastlane -v 2.177.0
          bundle install
      - name: Install tools
        run: |
          flutter precache
          flutter pub get
          cd ./ios
          pod install
      #- run: flutter pub get
      #- run: flutter build apk
      - run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --no-sound-null-safety
      - name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts for fastlane match
        run: |
          SSH_PATH="$HOME/.ssh"
          mkdir -p "$SSH_PATH"
          touch "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
          echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
          chmod 700 "$SSH_PATH"
          ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
          chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
          eval $(ssh-agent)
          ssh-add "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
        env:
          PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy to TestFlight/PGY
        run: |
          cd ./ios
          bundle exec fastlane beta
        env:
          FLUTTER_ROOT: ${{ secrets.FLUTTER_ROOT }}
          APPLE_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ID }}
          GIT_URL: ${{ secrets.GIT_URL }}
          PGY_USER_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_USER_KEY }}
          PGY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_API_KEY }}
          TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
          ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
          FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
          FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
          FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
          MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
          MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
          MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
          DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now packages are still being adjusted for null safety so till then you have to opt out of null safety while building by changing your main.dart like

```
// @dart=2.9
import 'src/my_app.dart';

main() {
  //...
}
```

The `//@dart=2.9` should do the trick. If not, try changing the environment version in pubspec.yaml like

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: how to make fastlane add `--no-sound-null-safety` config when build @Siddharth Agrawal

Comment: I could not downgrade the version beacuse all the code I changed to null safety @Siddharth Agrawal

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into a problem where I needed to bump the min SDK version for unrelated language features and am forced to sort out the null safety issues, while still needing to default builds to unsound null safety until all of the dependencies over which I have no control are converted. The documentation on this is abysmal, to say the least, and the fact there's no easy way to disable this from `pubspec.yaml` is ridiculous.

After a bit of poking around in the Flutter source code, I found that the way the `--no-sound-null-safety` flag is passed on is through the `EXTRA_FRONT_END_OPTIONS` environment variable. You should be able to force it on by simply adding it to your environment definitions. For Linux and Windows, hacking the `CMakeLists.txt` was sufficient to force it off by default:

```
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
    # Temporarily disable null safety checks until all packages have migrated
    EXTRA_FRONT_END_OPTIONS=--no-sound-null-safety
    ${FLUTTER_TOOL_ENVIRONMENT}
    "${FLUTTER_ROOT}/packages/flutter_tools/bin/tool_backend.sh"
      ${FLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM} ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
```

I also required this to get things like snapcraft builds working, as there is no option to manipulate the build options there.